# Change background color of button when clicking on a different button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I want to set the background color to white on a button called (.start_timer) when i click on another button called (.stop_timer). But when I click it, all my .start_timer buttons get triggered of course. But I need that one specified button. Can I make an ID on my buttons or what can i do?

I hope you understand what my problem is :)

```
$(this).css("background","red").delay(1000).queue(function() {
    $(this).css("background", "white").dequeue();
    $(".start_timer").click(function() {
        $(this).css("background","white");
     });
});
```

Comment: share your html code also

Comment: It is probably easiest to add an `id` to your button or use any other specific identifier (like it was suggested by @JitenderSingh).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the "start" button while clicking on "stop" then you must write the code in on click for the stop timer and use the class of stop button while using  background css